# Typescript type to convert array into strictly typed object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a type that would convert array with objects that has names(string) and values(generics) into strictly typed object.

Here's example what I want:

```
// MyObj contains name and value
const arr = [
  new MyObj("a", 1),
  new MyObj("b", "two"),
  new MyObj("c", true),
];

const map: TypeToConvertArrayIntoMap<typeof arr> = {} as any;

map.a; // Expect type 1 or number also ok
map.b; // Expect type "two" or string also ok
map.c; // Expect type true or boolean also ok
```

I've tried to write such type, but it gives me a type of all possible values, like `(1 | "two" | true).
Here's my full type snippet:

```
/** Type of the elements in an array */
type ElementOf<T> = T extends (infer E)[]
  ? E
  : T extends readonly (infer E)[]
  ? E
  : never;

type PossibleValues = number | string | boolean;

class MyObj<Name extends string, V extends PossibleValues> {
  constructor(public name: Name, public value: V) {}
}

type MyMap<TObjArr extends MyObj<string, PossibleValues>[]> = {
  [key in ElementOf<TObjArr>["name"]]: ElementOf<TObjArr>["value"];
};

const arr = [
  new MyObj("a", 1),
  new MyObj("b", "two"),
  new MyObj("c", true),
];

const map: MyMap<typeof arr> = {} as any;

map.a; // Expect type 1 or number also ok
// ^? (property) a: true | 1 | "two"
map.b; // Expect type "two" or string also ok
// ^? (property) a: true | 1 | "two"
map.c; // Expect type true or boolean also ok
// ^? (property) a: true | 1 | "two"
```

[Here's link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIBUE8AcFNwHsBm4AuALR8A28BbeAO3QGdwBLY8AQxtoCdHbpwRgAodORAUXxFSAeRQAeSAD5wAXijh4AD3QkAJhQAU1FPEbg%20ASgDaAXU7hwAfn3nwALnlKVxdeEbxaqpMVxstxHT1DU1trPlsHYngAN10Abk5uXnAABSQyMkoAI3wANVpcAFd4CjliQoIs3XAAH3AydEZqAHNa8CykJHx6BM4AY1xaDPAAWWhhLIArMQA5WiIFZTUKBqbiZoAacFzF51c0jOy8guKyaQBvWz7vVcK%209CRGDVhCnMo%208GJ5%20Ac5oi2Xm8PtETj9tgZwOcAL6cGFJBCjaAjWiwCQTSYAQWYu2WiPRYlWLS2B0yOXg%20SKJUkpmkckuFiMAGt4GxqPpBCR0KI0VMsYxqQAiL5EAUmEwOASETncyDovmCkGU0UJKG9a7EBp0bFyIy2KIAdzxUw0AtoAq2AEYDBs9fBDWN0SasubwAL0PqkALrbb7eNjQK%20i7GsVvSY1Td0OACCiHGNkaieAhUFr%20bJIVC6BR6NBetHYAA6WhxcDAYD6RQIe4YZIW5B6cqVaoFMhIZCMzil8AAPUsnDz%20ayxc7fAr8CricQbo9Arr9UaLTouBbbY7ZZ7fZR%20b6Q7LI8rkYnGEYxVnHS6HgYS9bSHbnZ7QA)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAg2Qw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are inferring the type under the exact index, but all values instead. To fix it you should map through the items of an array in the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) using [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content), where `K` will be the whole element in the array, and using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) make the key of the property to be `K['name']` and the value is straightforward:

```
type MyMap<TObjArr extends MyObj<string, PossibleValues>[]> = {
  [Item in TObjArr[number] as Item['name']]: Item['value'];
};
```

Testing:

```
const arr = [new MyObj('a', 1), new MyObj('b', 'two'), new MyObj('c', true)];

const map: MyMap<typeof arr> = {} as any;

map.a; // 1
map.b; // "two"
map.c; // true
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIDUCG6CuECUAvFAHb4C2qEATlAD5QLB3LkDmTUqccmHOQDcAKFEBjdDiRQAsiADyqAFYAeAHI4q0CAA9gEcgBNirdlwA0ULFH2GTxeEjSZcBIgD4oAb1FQoCThyc3wJYDg6AAowfAxkCQptCAAuKC0da1j4xIA3PEI0rABKXwBfUQrRUEh5EDkcMDUAFWUVAEE6BnsjUzq2tXMOTmtnFAxsAq8AbQBdbzI-AOmASUMqKA4oVtVOumnKGnpZqBkoNYgqaYBycmTr2dm0i6vr-I8HsTKxSWDWU66pCgBwgAHd+qootccNdrABGYrWchgiEqKGoWFQa7AUFwa6IigohRtKESTFsQjFWY-IIhYBQKiNNIKBpNGoQOAAMwBdAW5VOxCEIB+jLAADocMIoAB6aVQOGiUVi1BS2VQABEOLg6sVjTFElVcopEFEQA)